Empty Plotly Candlestick chart with yfinance.download()
I am trying to plot a simple Candlestick chart from OHLCV data retrieved by yfinance.
This is my code:
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime

tf = '1d'  # Time frame (daily)
asset = 'AAPL'  # Asset ticker (e.g., Apple)
start = '2019-01-01'  # Start date
end = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # End date is current date

df = yf.download(asset, start=start, end=end, interval=tf)

df['pct_chg'] = df['Close'].pct_change() * 100

df.index.name = 'timestamp'

# now plot the chart

hover_text = [f"Open: {open}<br>Close: {close}<br>Pct: {pct_chg:.2f}%" for open, close, pct_chg in zip(df['Open'], df['Close'], df['pct_chg'])]

# Create a candlestick chart using Plotly
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(
        x=df.index,
        open=df['Open'],
        high=df['High'],
        low=df['Low'],
        close=df['Close'],
        hovertext=hover_text,
        hoverinfo='text'
    )])

# Update layout
fig.update_layout(
        title='Candlestick chart',
        xaxis_title='Date',
        yaxis_title='Price',
        xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
        template='plotly_dark')

# Show the plot
fig.show()

Data is correctly downloaded. However the graph does not show any candle.

Actually Pandas will use MultiIndexing if you put data downloaded from yahoo finance into a dataframe.
display(df) gives:

To remove the Ticker column multi-index which is not needed, just drop it:
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)

Then you get a regular dataframe and can plot it the way you did it:

